# Spinner selected item not responding to second time selection

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a couple spinners; one for text selection and the other to change the text color. I also have a global textview that I set the selected item to when the user makes the selection. 
When I select the font color from my color spinner the color of the global textview changes like it is supposed to. Then when I select another textview in mt textview spinner and select that same color my text newly selected textview color doesn't change. Pretty odd. But if I select different color than the last used color it changes the color of my newly selected textview. 
I tried calling notifydatachanged() on the color adapter after each color change but that didn't work. Is there any work around?
Here is the code.

```
private void setUpColorSpinner() {
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.font_colors, R.layout.spinner_list_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        //Apply the adapter to the spinner
        fColorspinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        fColorspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                switch (parent.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        //leave it blank to set the color to the default color
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.WHITE));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.BLACK));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.WHITE));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.BLUE));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.GREEN));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Yellow));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.RED));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.PURPLE));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.ORANGE));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.OLIVE));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }

private void setUpTextViewsSpinner() {
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> cardtext = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.textviews,
                R.layout.spinner_list_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        cardtext.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        fTextViewsspinner.setAdapter(cardtext);
        final DisplayMetrics tvsmetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(tvsmetrics);

        fTextViewsspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                switch (adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        //selectedText.setText("");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        selectedText = text1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        selectedText = text2;
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: What class contains these methods? Please show it in valid Java syntax: `class MyClass { ... methods go here ... }`. Also, when do you call these methods?

Comment: They are in the main activity class.

Comment: Basically, you should show us enough code so that we can copy and paste it, add the necessary imports, and then compile it ourselves.

Comment: My computer is so slow. I have a lot of code to post in here.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, there must be some problem in the event listener you are using.

You can try switching the event listeners to [OnItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) or [OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) whichever matches your requirement.

Comment: how would it work the first time if there a problem with my OnItemClickListener?